# Django-filter doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am trying to make a filter for one of my apps in django.
I have no idea how to do this but i have tried to follow [this](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) tutorial.

I have create a filter.py file in my app. Right or wrong? Which look like this:

```
import django_filters
from pubs.models import Pub
class PubFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Pub
        fields =[
            'county'
        ]
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(PubFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.filters['manufacturer'].extra.update(
            {'empty_label': 'All Manufacturers'})
```

and my view look like this:

```
from pubs.filter import PubFilter
class PubsListView(ListView):
    model = Pub
    template_name = 'pubs/pubs-list.html'

    def pubs_list(self):
        f = PubFilter(self.GET, queryset=Pub.objects.all())
        return render_to_response('pubs/pubs-list.html', {'filter': f})
```

adn then in my template i have add this lines:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% for obj in filter %}
    {{ obj.name }} - ${{ obj.county }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

and it don't work. The only thing i see is a button where who say "send".
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please check your indentation: is the `__init__` method really inside the `Meta` class? It shouldn't be.

Comment: No it isn't it went wrong when i copied and paste...

Comment: My guess: Your `Pub` model doesn't have a `manufacturer` field, but the model in the tutorial does!